# Include Inline JavaScript with Curly Brackets {} in XSL

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I am attempting to transform XML to HTML via an XSL file. Unfortunately, it does not allow me to use JavaScript curly Brackets {}. The following is a trivial example, but my actual code is much larger.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
    <xsl:output media-type="text/html; charset=UTF-8" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match='/'>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <title> Page Title</title>
            </head>
            <body onload="javascript: if(confirm('Are you sure?')) { return true;} else { return false;}">
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Visual Studio gives me the following error:

```
Expected token '}', found 'true'.  ...firm('Are you sure?')) { return  -->true<-- ;} else { return false;}
```

Is there any way to include inline JavaScript in XSL? I know that you can use `<![CDATA[  ]]>` to escape Javascript blocks. But how do I escape inline JavaScript?  My actual code is too large to re-write all inline JavaScript as script blocks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Curly braces in attributes of literal result elements are used for "attribute value templates", enclosing XPath expressions. So if you want to generate attributes containing curlies, you need to escape them by doubling up:

```
<body onload="javascript: if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {{ return true;}} else {{ return false;}}">
```

However, including large blocks of Javascript inside onXXX attributes is probably best avoided anyway: instead, just include a function call to code defined within `<script>`.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Unfortunately, I have no control of the HTML files, so your solution worked best because it is a simple search and replace.

Answer (score 5):

Try this, it should not require escaping:

```
<body>
  <xsl:attribute name="onload">
    javascript: if(confirm('Are you sure?')) { return true;} else { return false;}
  </xsl:attribute>
</body>
```