# Make a JSON from an XML file by XPATH

Tags: xml, json, xpath

I'm currently working on a program to import `XML` file and exporting some data in `JSON` format by using `XPATH`. However I have problem with `XPATH` special characters. My most confusing issues are **{** and **}** as constants not operators.
here is my code sample to grab the `JSON` out of the `XML` file.

```
{[}
[FOREACH({trackdata/disc/side/track})]
{{}
"track": {index/.},
"title": "{title/.}"
{}},
[ENDFOREACH]
{]}
```

And I need the Output of something like:

```
[
  {
    "track": 1,
    "title": "title 1"
  },
  {
    "track": 2,
    "title": "title 2"
  }
]
```

So, Is this possible at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include Inline JavaScript with Curly Brackets {} in XSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198163/include-inline-javascript-with-curly-brackets-in-xsl)

Comment: Google for "escape curly brackets in XPATH".

Comment: @torzaburo: This is not the same question, because my question is not about the `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer after searching other forums. For those who are interested in the answer; I should have placed those `XPATH` special characters into square brackets followed by doublequote. Like `["{"]`.
So, the code sniped above will be:

```
["["]
[FOREACH({trackdata/disc/side/track})]
["{"]
"track": {index/.},
"title": "{title/.}"
["}"],
[ENDFOREACH]
["]"]
```